# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in React + Solidity dapp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solidity

So I am working on a dapp and using React for the first time and having some trouble with my code on Line 59. I am tried a couple of the mentioned solutions here but still can't find the error (Cannot read property 'map' of undefined), Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[picture of error][1]

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="content">
        <h1>Add Product</h1>
        <form
          onSubmit={(event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            const name = this.productName.value;
            *const price = window.web3.utils.toWei(
              this.productPrice.value.toString(),
              "Ether"
            );
            this.props.createProduct(name, price);
          }}
        >
          <div className="form-group mr-sm-2">
            <input
              id="productName"
              type="text"*
              ref={(input) => {
                *this.productName = input
              }}
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Product Name"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group mr-sm-2">
            <input
              id="productPrice"
              type="text"
              ref={(input) => {
                this.productPrice = input
              }}
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Product Price"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
            Add Product
          </button>
        </form>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>*
        <h2>Buy Product</h2>
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">#</th>
              <th scope="col">Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Price</th>
              <th scope="col">Owner</th>
              <th scope="col"></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="productList">
            { this.props.products.map((product, key) => {
              return(
                <tr key={key}>
                  <th scope="row">{product.id.toString()}</th>
                  <td>{product.name}</td>
                  <td>{window.web3.utils.fromWei(product.price.toString(), 'Ether')} Eth</td>
                  <td>{product.owner}</td>
                  <td>
                    { !product.purchased
                      ? <button
                          name={product.id}
                          value={product.price}
                          onClick={(event) => {
                            this.props.purchaseProduct(event.target.name, event.target.value)
                          }}
                        >
                          Buy
                        </button>
                      : null
                    }
                    </td>
                </tr>
              )
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKq7F.png
```

Comment: So `this.props.products` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tbody id="productList">
        { this.props.products.map((product, key) => {
          return(
```

change this too

```
<tbody id="productList">
        { this.props.products.map((product, key) => (
```

get rid of the brackets and the return and all the mapped items be inside the parenthesis after the arrow.

Comment: Also looking back where are these props being passed into this component? A component is passed props from the parent element. and takes them in from the constructor for a class component.

Comment: you need to have products set to an actual value. if its a prop it needs to be imported through a constructor.

Comment: The components can be found here https://github.com/terrafirmatrekker/Nakamoto-List/tree/master/src